# Adding Custom header in react-navigation 5

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I know how to implement header in navigation 3, but I'm having trouble passing the `navigation` to my header component in version 5.

(HomeStack.js)

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { Button } from 'react-native';
import Home from '../screens/home';
import ReviewDetails from '../screens/reviewDetails';
import Header from '../shared/header';

const Stack = createStackNavigator()

export default Navigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#f4511e',
        },
        headerTintColor: '#fff',
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight: 'bold',
        },
      }}  
    >
      <Stack.Screen 
        name='Home'
        component={Home} 
        options={{ 
          headerTitle: ({navigation}) => <Header navigation={navigation}/> 
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen name='ReviewDetails' component={ReviewDetails} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}
```

(header.js)

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

export default function Header({ navigation }) {

    const openMenu = () => {
        navigation.openDrawer();
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.header}>
            <MaterialIcons name='menu' size={28} onPress={openMenu} style={styles.icon}/>
            <View>
                <Text style={styles.headerText}>GameZone</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    header: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    headerText: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 20,
        color: '#333',
        letterSpacing: 1,
    },
    icon: {
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 16
    }

});
```

I think the only problem is how to pass the navigation var.  to the header component in order to open and close the drawer. I am struggling with this problem. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: try using `navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer());` instead of `navigation.openDrawer()`

[reference](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-based-navigation/#opening-and-closing-drawer)

Comment: ok, but how do I pass the navigation object to the header component ? Since it is not working like this

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, instead of passing your header component into the `headerTitle` prop, try to pass it into the `header` prop instead

[reference](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator#header)